# How to show a list in a grid/table inside a window container?

Tags: extjs

I have created a window as below:

```
Ext.create({
            xtype: 'window',
            title: "Name",
            closable: true,
            centered: true,         
            maxWidth: 1000,
            minHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: 430,
            minWidth: 350,
            scrollable: true,           
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                html: record.data.Name,
                style: 'padding:10px'
            }]
}));
```

and my store as below:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     data : [
         {Name: 'Peter, John, Mary'}        
     ]
 });
```

I want to show the name as a grid/table (which ever is fine) inside my window container. Like below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFNn.png)

Can someone  help me with this?

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using? Which toolkit: modern or classic?

Comment: exjs 6.5.3 modern

Comment: Where is the grid and User model code?

Comment: {Name: 'Peter, John, Mary'} <-- What is it?

Comment: its static data that i stored for Name in the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not correct. Anyway..
[image]

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'window',
    title: "Name",
    closable: true,
    centered: true,
    maxWidth: 1000,
    minHeight: 300,
    maxHeight: 430,
    minWidth: 350,
    scrollable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        store: {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Peter'
            }, {
                name: 'John'
            }, {
                name: 'Mary'
            }]
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 1
        }]
    }]
}).show();
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. but in my case  name is actually stored like this {Peter, John, Mary} in the datastore (like a list) .. do we need a for loop to show them in separate rows?

Comment: Ok, let's begin from the beginning. Grid rows represent the records (models) of the store. If you have one record you will have one row in the grid. In your case you will have to split the record value and put the data into the store of the grid.